# Do .dll 's retain any references added to your project?

Tags: c#, dll, transfer, rainmeter

**PROBLEM**
I created a C# project that implements the System.Management.Automation reference (allowing me to write powershell commands in my project).
[image][image]

I compiled the project and copied the dll to the plugins folder of my Rainmeter application so that I could leverage it along with the other dll 's Rainmeter comes with. [image]

This works perfectly on my machine (64 bit); however, I want to load this same configuration on another server (also 64 bit). Both machines are using the same installation of the .NET framework (4.5).

According to this [source](https://forum.rainmeter.net/viewtopic.php?t=3878), I should be able to simply copy the Rainmeter folder with the included dll and it should run without any problems (I'm using the portable installation of Rainmeter).

I receive the error "System.IO.FileNotFoundException" unless I remove the "SystemVersion.dll" that I created, when running Rainmeter on another server.
[image]

**QUESTION**
Since the issue is clearly the dll I have added, I'm assuming the reference is not being added to the dll?

=========================================================================
**EDIT**
As per @Hackerman 's answer, the issue was that the dll was unable to find my reference. The path for System.Management.Automation required powershell version 3.0 to be installed on the machine in order to load the reference.
[image] 
My server was running powershell version 2.0, but after installing version 3.0 the dll was able to load the reference and Rainmeter would display my results as expected.

Comment: Is this a WinForms project?

Comment: @Hackerman No, it is a dll. Output type is a Class Library.

Comment: Ok, now I have a better understanding....you created a Rainmeter plugin, but when you include your dll in the plugins folrder, Rainmeter doesn't works, right?

Comment: @Hackerman That is correct.

Comment: Can you post the full error message....I think that maybe your dll can't find the `System.Management.Automation` assembly...and answering your question, no, when you build your dll, it doesn't embed the referenced dll...

Comment: @Hackerman Sorry, had a few meetings to attend. ...
You were right about the dll being unable to find the 'System.Management.Automation assembly'. The full path in properties is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\**WindowsPowerShell\3.0**\System.Management.Automation.dll
  
The server I was targeting did not have powershell version 3.0, so it could not load the reference.

Comment: @Hackerman Post your answer to my question, as well as your suspicion that the dll was unable to find the 'System.Management.Automation' as an "Answer" below. I will accept it and add an edit to my post showing where the issue was found.

Comment: Consider it done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build your `class library`, the references don't get `embedded` on your final `dll`. The `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` that you are getting is because your dll can't load the `System.Managem‌​ent.Automation.dll` reference on the destination server. Installing `PowerShell 3.0` on the server should resolve the issue.